# Canned Regexps for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Does Ruby have a gem that provides a canned set of regular expressions (ala Perl's Regexp::Common module)?  If not, how does the community share commonly-needed regexps?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, kind of.

There is a gem called [ruby_regex](https://github.com/eparreno/ruby_regex) that does this exact thing. From their github page:

```
Add to your Gemfile

  gem 'ruby_regex'

In the models

  validates_format_of :email, :with => RubyRegex::Email
```

And they have listed regex for:

```
RubyRegex::Url
RubyRegex::Domain
RubyRegex::Email
RubyRegex::Username
RubyRegex::USSocialSecurity
RubyRegex::GeneralPostalCode
RubyRegex::ZIPCode
RubyRegex::CreditCard
RubyRegex::MasterCard
RubyRegex::Visa
RubyRegex::TwitterUsername
RubyRegex::DeliciousUsername
RubyRegex::SlidesahreUsername
RubyRegex::GithubUsername
RubyRegex::UUID
RubyRegex::DBDate
RubyRegex::DBDatetime
RubyRegex::SpanishBankAccountNumber
RubyRegex::Dni
```

I'm not sure if they support anything else. There are lots of little one-off projects for this. But I haven't been able to find anything nearly as complete as the perl module.

I also found another one called [Cregexp](https://github.com/hulihanapplications/cregexp) that has limited numbers of them as well.

Comment: Hmm, not much in either one of those, but at least it's a start.  I guess Ruby could use a "Damian Conway" - like contributor to help flesh this out?  Thanks for your help.